# Is it possible to restore the cursor style in a terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, ansi

It's possible, with ANSI codes, to modify the cursor shape (block, underscore or line) and whether it's blinking  or not.

My program is doing just that. But, is it possible to get the cursor style so it can be restored later (when my program exits)?

One can get the cursor position and even mouse position with ANSI codes, but it seams to me that we can only set the cursor style and not retrieve it or even reset it to an older state.

Comment: See https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h3-Device-Control-functions (DECRQSS request for DECSCUSR) for xterm or compatible.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. Unfortunately, after testing it, it doesn't work in a lot of terminals and I'm seeking something more cross-compatible.

Comment: for reference, seems this was implemented in crossterm/reedline: https://github.com/crossterm-rs/crossterm/issues/646

Comment: @mb21 As you said yourself on the issue thread: "This was closed in #742 although that PR only added SetCursorStyle and no command to get the cursor style?"